# Prove that the polynomial $p$ exists with $degree< \operatorname{dim}V$

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is regarding an old post from the site, namely:

[$T$ is normal if and only if exist polynomial $p$ s.t $T^{*}=p(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455402/t-is-normal-if-and-only-if-exist-polynomial-p-s-t-t-pt)

My question is : How do you prove that such a polynomial has $\deg< \dim V$? It seems weird to me that the polynomial can not have degree equal to $\dim V.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is normal on a complex inner product space $X$ of finite dimension $N$, then $T$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, which must also be a basis of eigenvectors for $T^*$ because
$$
            \|(T-\lambda I)x\|=\|(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)x\|,\;\;\; x\in V,\;\lambda\in\mathbb{C}.
$$
If $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n\}$ is the set of distinct eigenvalues of $T$, then
$$
           P_j = \frac{1}{\Pi_{k\ne j}(\lambda_j-\lambda_k)}\Pi_{k\ne j}(T-\lambda_k I)
$$
is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{N}(T-\lambda_j I)=\mathcal{N}(T^*-\overline{\lambda_j}I)$. Therefore,
$$
                   T=\sum_{j}\lambda_j P_j,\;\;\; T^*=\sum_{j}\overline{\lambda_j}P_j.
$$
In particular, $T^*$ is a polynomial in $T$. (Likewise, $T$ is a polynomial in $T^*$.) The order of the polynomial is less than $N=\dim(X)$.

Comment: I am not quite following what you are doing. I have trouble understanding how you are concluding that  "The order of the polynomial is less than =dim()"

Comment: @MathBro $P_j$ is a product of $N-1$ linear factors with $T$ and $I$, where $N$ is the number of distinct eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $T$ is nilotent, there is nothing to do as $T=\mathbf 0$. Now assume $T\neq \mathbf 0$.
Further suppose you have $d\geq n$ and
$p\big(T\big) = a_0 I + a_1 T + .... +a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+ a_nT^n + ... + a_dT^d$

by Caley Hamilton
$T^n$ may be written as a linear combination of $\{I, T,...,T^{n-1}\}$, and so may  $T^{n+1}$, ...., and so may $T^d$

so you can re-write $p$ to have degree $\leq n-1$.